# Attribute error:module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, spyder, mysql-connector

I'm running MacOS Mojave, trying to connect to MySQL using mysql-python connector, through spyder ide (python3)

But I am getting the error:

```py
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/omgboi.py", line 5, in <module>
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='hariom21feb',database='test')

AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

I tried installing and reinstalling mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python through bash but it didn't work. I've also tried changing my file's name but that didn't work as well. This is the code:

```py
import mysql.connector
import random
first_names=['Jodee,Marielle,Phillip,Colby,Stephany,Dione,Grover,Napoleon,Nicholas,Alysa,Noma,Leta,Ciera,Donny,Buc,Iren,Renato,Glory,Stacia,Bennie,Soo,Mitzie,Kaci,Peggy,Hilma,Melva,Cindie,Miyoko,Melina,Cammy,Blanche,Rhea,Jill,Kellye,Ailene,Vida,Alva,Sau,Hollis,Oswaldo,Marty']
last_names=['Bula,Bibi,Rolf,Tayna,Ardith,Art,Jeannetta,Patrina,Ronny,Maida,Cleopatra,Sherry,Vincenza,Sheri,Sherlyn,Shayne,Geneva,Javier,Celine,Saran,Shari,Boris,Gwyneth,Summer,Maryellen,Rufina,Essie,Palma,Rafael,Cordell,Jude,Jenine,Manuel,Cleveland,Daphine,Lavina,Candi,Rossie,Brunilda,Gilberte,Nick,Hoyt,Lucius,Ardis,Tyler,Dwain,Caleb,Aide,Mckinley,Margurite']
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='hariom21feb',database='test')
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
fkey=random.randint(0,49)
lkey=random.randint(0,49)
nkey=random.randint(0,50)
for i in range(nkey):
    query=('insert into test value(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)')
    tup=('L5W4NW',first_names(fkey),last_names(lkey),'2970','completed')
    mycursor.execute(query,tup)
mydb.commit()
```

Any ideas about what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How did you installed Connector/Python?

The PyPI package `mysql-connector` is deprecated, you should use the official `mysql-connector-python`.

The easiest and recommended way is using `pip`:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

More details about installation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/installation.html