# Getting AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector' in python

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am on windows 10 and using python3.9.

I installed the pagkage
*>python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python*

Now I try to run a simple program

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="pythonDB"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


mycursor.execute("SELECT * FORM customers")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

I am getting the following error when running
*>python3 select.py*

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Python_w3school\mysql\select.py", line 1, in 
import mysql.connector
File "C:\Users\pawar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector_*init*_.py", line 42, in 
import dns.resolver
File "C:\Users\pawar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 20, in 
import socket
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 54, in 
import os, sys, io, selectors
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\selectors.py", line 12, in 
import select
File "G:\Python_w3school\mysql\select.py", line 3, in 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'

Comment: Does it need to do anything with python3??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Python3 is not taking SQL directly inside the execute function.
Assign the query to a variable and pass it to the execute() function.

> It worked for me!!!

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers"
mycursor.execute(sql)
```

Also try try renaming the file if it is something like **select.py** to **select_customers.py**

Answer (score 0):

try these:

[AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503776/attributeerror-module-mysql-has-no-attribute-connector)

[Attribute error:module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381315/attribute-errormodule-mysql-has-no-attribute-connector/56392886)

basically change the import to

`from mysql import connector`